# Run for loop via ssh

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, quoting

Good day All,

I'm attempting to run a for loop via SSH. The loop is used to get the last login of each user that has an account on the server,

```
ssh 172.20.2.1 '''for i in `cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}'`; do last -n 1 $i | sed -e '/^$/{N;d;}'; done'''
```

I am getting the error,

```
    bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
   -bash: d: command not found
   -bash: }; done: command not found
```

I Googled but didn't get much to go on.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because you are using `'''` to quote your command. Since you are also using single `'` to quote your `awk` and `sed` commands, the shell thinks the command is over and gets confused. As far as I know, there is no such thing as `'''`; the first two `'` are ignored since they simply define an empty string and the last is taken as an opening quote which is closed by the opening quote of your `awk`. You can see this if you look at how your code is highlighted in your question.

The simplest solution is to use single quotes to enclose the command and double quotes for the `sed` and `awk`. However, you will then need to escape the `$1` in the `awk` script so that it's not interpreted as a shell variable. You're also complicating things for no reason. All you really need is:

```
ssh localhost 'cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | 
    while read i; do last -n 1 $i | sed -e "/^$/{N;d;}"; done'
```